# Python/psycopg2 WHERE IN statement

Tags: python, psycopg2, where-in

What is the correct method to have the list (countryList) be available via %s in the SQL statement?

```
# using psycopg2
countryList=['UK','France']

sql='SELECT * from countries WHERE country IN (%s)'
data=[countryList]
cur.execute(sql,data)
```

As it is now, it errors out after trying to run "WHERE country in (ARRAY[...])". Is there a way to do this other than through string manipulation?

Thanks

Answer (score 208, accepted):

For the `IN` operator, you want a [tuple](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#tuples-adaptation) instead of [list](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#lists-adaptation), and remove parentheses from the SQL string.

```
# using psycopg2
data=('UK','France')

sql='SELECT * from countries WHERE country IN %s'
cur.execute(sql,(data,))
```

During debugging you can check that the SQL is built correctly with

```
cur.mogrify(sql, (data,))
```

Comment: If you're having trouble even after reading this answer re-read it again very slowly. It's a tuple of tuples and you must remove the parans around the %s if you have them there. This tripped me up because a simpler test of mine used only a single value and everything worked. Just follow this exactly as Bryan wrote it out.

Comment: cur.mogrify is a great tip. I keep forgetting about that one... 

Comment: I got error 'psycopg.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "$1" LINE 1: SELECT * from countries WHERE country IN $1'

Comment: Use `ANY` instead. See that doc: https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/from_pg2.html#you-cannot-use-in-s-with-a-tuple

Comment: Please edit this answer as it is not valid for `psycopg >= 3.0` - see dzav's comments or mjuopperi's answer

Answer (score 62):

To expland on the answer a little and to address named parameters, and converting lists to tuples:

```
countryList = ['UK', 'France']

sql = 'SELECT * from countries WHERE country IN %(countryList)s'

cur.execute(sql, { # You can pass a dict for named parameters rather than a tuple. Makes debugging hella easier.
    'countryList': tuple(countryList), # Converts the list to a tuple.
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip on passing in a dict. That is much much better.

Comment: Can this be implemented with multiple WHERE x IN clauses and multiple lists in the dictionary?

Comment: Correction: @Odisseo Yes, with the almighty OR. Eg: `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IN %(list1)s OR col IN %(list2)s", {'list1': tuple(1,2,3), 'list2' = tuple(4,5,6)})`

Comment: Warning, this will throw a postgres syntax error if the list / tuple is empty.  Alternatively, you may use a WHERE ANY statement as shown in other answers.

Answer (score 20):

You could use a python list directly as below. It acts like the IN operator in SQL and also handles a blank list without throwing any error.

```
data=['UK','France']
sql='SELECT * from countries WHERE country = ANY (%s)'
cur.execute(sql,(data,))
```

source:
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#lists-adaptation

Comment: Can also use accepted answer but with 

`cur.execute(sql, (tuple(data),))`

Answer (score 13):

Since the psycopg3 question was marked as a duplicate, I'll add the answer to that here too.

In psycopg3, you can not use `in %s` with a tuple, like you could in psycopg2. Instead you have to use  `ANY()` and wrap your list inside another list:

```py
conn.execute("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = ANY(%s)", [[10,20,30]])
```

Docs: https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/from_pg2.html#you-cannot-use-in-s-with-a-tuple

Comment: More on this topic can be found here: https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/from_pg2.html

Answer (score -1):

I'm using `'row_factory': dict_row` and the following works for me:

SQL: `... where col_name = ANY(%(col_name)s);`

Python: `connection.execute(sql, {'col_name': ['xx',...,'yy']})`

Comment: This solution is already provided by existing answers (using  a dict for params is a trivial difference)

Comment: @snakecharmerb No, my answer differs

Comment: How does it differ? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54379662/5320906) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75040183/5320906)  both  seem identical save for the style of parameter substitution.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Both solution uses `(%s)` placeholder and raw array with values, while my solution uses named placeholder `column_name` and dict with a column name key and array values