# Python/pg8000 WHERE IN statement

Tags: python, where-in, python-db-api, pg8000

What is the correct method to have the tuple (names) be available via %s in the SQL statement?

```
names = ('David', 'Isaac')
sql = 'SELECT * from names WHERE name IN %s'
cur.execute(sql,(names,))
```

The response in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28117658/5879128 works for psycopg2 but does not work in pg8000.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Generate the proper number of placeholders. In pg8000 [the placeholder defaults to `%s`](http://pybrary.net/pg8000/dbapi.html#pg8000.dbapi.paramstyle).
2. Interpolate placeholders to the query string.
3. Execute SQL-injection-safe query.

Like so:

```
sql = 'SELECT * from names WHERE name IN ({})'.format( ','.join(['%s']*len(names)) )
# results in -> 'SELECT * from names WHERE name IN (%s,%s)'
cur.execute(sql,(names,))
```