# Can I aggreate multiple inputs on a endpoint designed for a single result?

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi

I'm using fastapi but I think this is maybe a general python/postgres question.

```
@app.get("/company/{company_ticker}/carbon-footprint")
async def getCompanyFootprint(
    company_ticker: str,
    http_client: aiohttp.ClientSession = fastapi.Depends(http_client)
):

    query_statement = "select * from company.carbon where upper(ticker) = $1 order by year ASC"
    #sending query to DB then return the results as a json
    result_data = await main_db_instance.fetch_rows(query_statement, company_ticker.upper())
    result_data_json = jsonable_encoder(result_data)
    return JSONResponse(result_data_json)
```

But I want to also have a different endpoint that has similar logic as the above endpoint but aggreated over multiple inputs:

```
@app.post("/portfolio/analytics/carbon-footprint")
async def getPortfolioCarbonFootprint(
    tickers: list = Body(...),
    http_client: aiohttp.ClientSession = fastapi.Depends(http_client)
):
  
    portfolioDF = pd.DataFrame()
    #take the list of inputs and cycle through them one by one.
    for element in tickers:
        jsonResults=  jsonable_encoder (await getCompanyFootprint(company_ticker=element.upper() )  )['body']
        elementDF=pd.read_json(jsonResults)
        portfolioDF = portfolioDF.append(elementDF, ignore_index = True)  
    portfolioDF = portfolioDF.select_dtypes(['number'])
    gr=portfolioDF.groupby('year').agg('mean')
    return portfolioDF.to_json()
```

As you can see I call the function one at a time but if a list of 1000 items is sent it's very very slow.

I thought maybe I could modify my postgres query to:

```
"select * from company.carbon where upper(ticker) = any($1) order by year ASC"
```

but I'm getting an error at company_ticker for the function getCompanyFootprint. I think it's due me trying to send it a list instead of a simple string.

Is there a way to have the endpoint accept a single string (via get) or multiple strings in a list(when calling the function directly)? Or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: which postgres library/driver? psychopg2? Infact you'll have to modify getCompanyFootPrint definition to accept iterable and then take some clue from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117576/python-psycopg2-where-in-statement

Comment: @Avezan so something like in ($1) but can I still have a single input when accessing from the URL?