# How to use WHERE IN with psycopg?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg3

I have a table like this:

| id | topic_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | '1' |
| 3 | '1.1' |
| ... | ... |
| 21 | '4' |

and I would like to get a list of `id`s corresponding to their `topic_id`s.

I can query the database directly just fine:

```sql
SELECT id FROM topics WHERE topic_id IN ('1', '4')

# returns [2, 21]
```

But when I do it via psycopg (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42013378/1312522)), I get no results:

```
topic_ids = ['1', '4']

with psycopg.connect(os.environ['DB_CONNECTION']) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        sql = "SELECT id FROM topics WHERE topic_id IN (%(ids)s)"
        cur.execute(sql, {"ids": tuple(topic_ids)})

        cur.fetchall() # returns []
```

I can only get a single id out with

```
        cur.execute(sql, {"ids": topic_ids[0]})

        cur.fetchall() # I get [(2,)]
```

---

How can I get the whole list out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build a dynamic `WHERE IN (...)` clause, with a variable number of `%s` placeholders, and then bind the correct tuple.

```py
where = "WHERE topic_id IN (?" + ", ?"*(len(topic_ids) - 1) + ")"
sql = "SELECT id FROM topics " + where
cur.execute(sql, tuple(topic_ids))
cur.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using IN, you can use `=ANY` and then have python bind the entire array to one placeholder.

```
sql = "SELECT id FROM topics WHERE topic_id =ANY (%(ids)s)"
cur.execute(sql, {"ids": topic_ids})
```